# Why is the request body blank when the content-type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded?

Tags: cherrypy

I am receiving a request with content-type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. When I try to read the body of the request using `cherrypy.request.body.read()` the results is `b''`.

I seem to be able to access the request form parameters using any of these:

`cherrypy.request.params`

`cherrypy.request.body.params`

`cherrypy.request.body.request_params`

But this is inconvenient for my use case, I want to be able to obtain the raw request body regardless of content-type. Also the above 3 give me a dictionary, which isn't the exact format that the request had in its body. Is there a way to do that with cherrypy? Or is this functionality hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what are you trying to accomplish by not using the already parsed body that correspond to the defined `Content-Type`... but you can process the body of the request yourself configuring: `cherrypy.request.process_request_body = False` and read the body with something like:

```
cherrypy.request.rfile.read(cherrypy.request.headers['Content-Length'])
```

For more information see: https://github.com/cherrypy/cherrypy/blob/master/cherrypy/_cprequest.py#L292-L315

Fragment of relevant parts of that url:

```
rfile = None
"""
If the request included an entity (body), it will be available
as a stream in this attribute. However, the rfile will normally
be read for you between the 'before_request_body' hook and the
'before_handler' hook, and the resulting string is placed into
either request.params or the request.body attribute.
You may disable the automatic consumption of the rfile by setting
request.process_request_body to False, either in config for the desired
path, or in an 'on_start_resource' or 'before_request_body' hook.
WARNING: In almost every case, you should not attempt to read from the
rfile stream after CherryPy's automatic mechanism has read it. If you
turn off the automatic parsing of rfile, you should read exactly the
number of bytes specified in request.headers['Content-Length'].
Ignoring either of these warnings may result in a hung request thread
or in corruption of the next (pipelined) request.
"""

process_request_body = True
"""
If True, the rfile (if any) is automatically read and parsed,
and the result placed into request.params or request.body.
"""

body = None
"""
If the request Content-Type is 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
or multipart, this will be None. Otherwise, this will be an instance
of :class:`RequestBody<cherrypy._cpreqbody.RequestBody>` (which you
can .read()); this value is set between the 'before_request_body' and
'before_handler' hooks (assuming that process_request_body is True."""
```

Comment: I wanted to read the raw request body without having to check both the `body` and `params` fields (also wasn't sure if there was going to be other options beyond that...). Your answer allows me to do that, by disabling the extra processing that cherrypy does. I had checked the documentation, but did not check the code itself. Thanks.